# General expression for $\sin(2^n x)$

Tags: trigonometry, products

Are there general expressions for $\sin(2^n x)$ and $\cos(2^n x)$ that only involve $\sin x$ and $\cos x$, and that moreover involve only **polynomial** (in $n$) number of terms?

**Edit**:

$2^n$ is not polynomial in $n$. A proof that no such expression exits (perhaps using the uniquness of Chebyshev polynomials?) would be gladly accepted.

Comment: For $\sin(2^n x)$, you can repeatedly use $\sin (2x)=2\sin x\cos x$, but you'll end up with a $2^n$ term flying around. You can so something analogous for the cosine.

Comment: $$\sin 2^rx=\sin 2(2^{r-1}x)=2\sin2^{r-1}x\cos 2^{r-1}x $$

Put $r=1,2,3,\cdots ,n-1,n$

Comment: @PeterTamaroff - I know, which is why I specifically stated " polynomial (in n) number of terms".

Comment: My initial idea is to use $e^{i 2^n x}=(e^{ix})^{2^n}=(\cos{x}+i \sin{x})^{2^n}$.

Comment: You may be interested in Chebychev polynomial : for every $n \ge 1$, there exist real a polynomial $T_n$ such that $\cos(nx) = T_n(cos(x))$. In particular $T_2 = 2X^2-1$ and $T_{2^n} = T_2 \circ \ldots \circ T_2$ ($T_2$ composed $n$ times with itself).

Comment: The first thing you need to define is term. Are you looking for an expression of the form $\sin(2^nx)=P(\sin(x),\cos(x))$ where $P$ is a polynomial and then you count as term the terms of $P$? Are you looking for more general expressions and you really want to count the number of operations necessary to compute it? These questions are not the same, so it would be good to specify. What kind of expressions you are looking for, and what is a term?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand the spirit of the question, no such expressions exist. First, $\cos(2^n \theta)$ is even, so a polynomial in $\sin \theta$ and $\cos \theta$ that is equal to $\cos(2^n \theta)$ contains only even powers of $\sin\theta$, and therefore may be written as a polynomial in $\cos\theta$, as marty cohen notes.

Now, $\cos(2^n \theta)$ has $2^{n+1}$ simple zeros in the interval $[0, 2\pi]$. By contrast, if $p_n$ is a polynomial with real coefficients and "polynomial-in-$n$ terms" (my interpretation of the original question), then $p_n$ has polynomial-in-$n$ roots in the interval $[-1, 1]$ by Descartes rule of signs, and consequently $p_n(\cos \theta)$ vanishes only polynomial-in-$n$ times in $[0, 2\pi]$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE!

Answer (score 1):

I might be missing something here... but the identity $\cos(2x)=2\cos^2(x)-1$ can be trivially applied $n$ times to obtain an *expression* with polynomial length:
$$\begin{eqnarray}
\cos(2^nx) & = & 2\left(\cos(2^{n-1}x)\right)^2-1 \\
& = & 2\left(2\left(\cos(2^{n-2}x)\right)^2-1\right)^2-1 \\
& = & 2\left(2\left(2\left(\cos(2^{n-3}x)\right)^2-1\right)^2-1\right)^2-1 \\
& & \vdots \\
& = & 2\left(2\left(\ldots \left(2\left(2\cos^2 x-1\right)^2-1\right)^2\ldots\right)^2-1\right)^2-1 \\
\end{eqnarray}$$

Note that this results in just *one* occurrence of the $\cos x$ term and the whole expression contains $n$ twos, $n$ squarings and $n$ subtractions of $1$. Thus, length-wise it's polynomial. Of course, getting rid of the squares would blow the size of the formula up exponentially.

Similar approach can be used for $\sin(2^nx)$; it suffices to notice that $$\sin(2^nx)=2^n\sin(x)\cos(x)\cos(2x)\cos(4x)\ldots\cos(2^{n-1}x)$$ and apply the expression above to the $\cos(2^kx)$ terms (resulting in expression of length quadratic in $n$). If one is interested in *evaluating* the expression, it's possible to do much better (thanks to the high level of redundancy).